# Blender's view distance

Tags: interface

can I make the blenders view distance much further? 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can.
When not in camera view,  like this:[image]
For the camera view,  like this: [image]

Answer (score 1):

If you open the right sidebar ('N' key shortcut), then go to the View tab and increase the End value for the clipping range. Is can cause artifacts if the range is too large so you might need to increase the Start value too if you are working on large scale objects.
[image]